# How to implement multiple Labels horizontal, which can grow vertical if not enough space is available with Auto-Layout

Tags: swift, user-interface

I need a solution to display tags (each as a UILabel) in a UITableViewCell, which should be aligned horizontal, but growing vertical if the horizontal space is not enough. It should work with Auto-Layout and automatically fits the width of the current width of the cell.

I attached an image which hopefully visualise the issue. It is a cell, where a label is on top. Below this label is the tag view where the Label-Tags should be displayed.

[image]

I already used a vertical StackView which contains the label and multiple horizontal StackViews filled with the Label-Tags. For this I have to take the max width and calculate the current width to decide a new horizontal Tag-StackView is needed.

This works, but doesn't fit if the orientation changes. I doesn't looking for a solution which observe orientation changes and updates the Cell afterwards. I am looking for an Auto-Layout solution and hope anyone has a nice solution for this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @RajeshKumarR thanks. I already thought about a UICollectionView, but wouldn't be this an overkill for each cell?

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the stack views and just configure this with simple straightforward auto layout. Pin each row labels horizontally in series, with their heights set to be equal so that if one grows vertically, they all do. Set the compression resistance of the labels differently from one another so that there is no ambiguity as to what should happen when the cell width is too small for the label text. Now pin everything vertically in series to the cell content view so that the cell will resize when the labels do.

Comment: thank for your input, but I think this will only works if I have a fixed number of labels in a row and not for dynamic amount of Tag-Labels. 
What you mention is kind of `|-16-[Label1]-16-[Label2]-16-[Label3]-16-|` where each Label has the same height, different compression resistance to each other and all vertically to the content view. But how should this growing down dynamic if Label 3 has no place in the first row?